# FCM error in IOS : The caller does not have permission?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase node Admin API to send push notification to Android and IOs devices. Android is working fine but in IOS, I can generate FCM token but when I send push notification to IOS token from the node js (firebase admin code), I am getting the below error:

```
 Error sending message: { Error: The caller does not have permission
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/MAC/Documents/Workspace/Nodejs/msever/Mserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/MAC/Documents/Workspace/Nodejs/msever/Mserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/Users/MAC/Documents/Workspace/Nodejs/msever/Mserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:250:16)
    at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/Users/MAC/Documents/Workspace/Nodejs/msever/Mserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:280:16)
    at FirebaseMessagingRequestHandler.handleHttpError (/Users/MAC/Documents/Workspace/Nodejs/msever/Mserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:125:50)
    at /Users/MAC/Documents/Workspace/Nodejs/msever/Mserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:113:23
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  errorInfo:
   { code: 'messaging/mismatched-credential',
     message: 'The caller does not have permission' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

I am using react native for Android and IOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your error info

> code: 'messaging/mismatched-credential'

Firebase [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors) says :

The credential used to authenticate this SDK does not have permission to send messages to the device corresponding to the provided registration token. Make sure the credential and registration token both belong to the same Firebase project. See [Add Firebase to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)  for documentation on how to authenticate the Admin SDKs.

You probably configured Android correctly but you missed some small thing for iOS. Follow [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) to setup iOS client :)

Comment: yeah, but I can't figured it out. I have created new key in apple console and added the new auth key in the firebase project but still same

Comment: can you recommend some easy way to from start to end to create FCM in apple?

Comment: You may follow the link provided in my answer. Nothing is better than official documentation. So I recommend you to follow that as it is the most latest one

Comment: I have delete the old FCM app and re-create it for Android and IOS. Now server is showing success for both android and IOS but I am seeing the notification only on android. Nothing on IOS

Comment: did you actually upload your push certificates (.p12 files) to the Firebase console? I've seen this error before, and tokens were successfully generated after uploading those.

Comment: refer [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/281) it might help !

Comment: I can successfully generate the FCM token using react-native-firebase. If I can received FCM, can I say that APNS must be working fine, otherwise FCM would not be generated. Right?

Comment: Yes, I had uploaded the push certificates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187557/discussion-between-firu-and-shubham1164).

Answer (score 0):

In my case from what I could figure out, push notifications worked on android but iOS for some reason gave me this exact same error.

What I did was:

1. redownload `GoogleService-Info.plist` from the firebase console making sure it's the one for iOS device
2. removed the old one in the project
3. add the new one making sure the `copy items if needed` option was checked
4. test that you receive the push notifications via the console or the admin sdk function